# Ajuda Python em orientação a objetos

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

O que há de errado nesse código? O compilador aponta erro na linha 8...

```
class Pai(object):
    Nome='Carlos'
    Sobrenome='Maria'
    Residencia='Rio de Janeiro'
class Filha(Pai):
    Nome='Luciana'
    def __init__(self, humor):
        self.humor = humor

f = Filha('alegre')
print(f.Nome)
print(Nome.Pai)
print(f.Sobrenome)
print(f.Residencia)
print(f.olho)
```

Comment: Que erro está sendo apresentado? É erro de compilação (tipo, erro de sintaxe ou algo assim) ou erro de execução (resultado incorreto, exceção, etc)? Há vários problemas no seu código - por exemplo, em `print(Nome.Pai)` - mas pra te ajudar melhor seria bom saber exatamente do que o compilador está reclamando.

Comment: O erro é este: expected an indented block

Comment: Estou aprendendo oop em python agora vim do C e me perco em oop mas valeo pela ajuda

Comment: Por acaso você está misturando espaços com tabs? A sintaxe do código postado parece correta, não há razão para dar esse erro. Sugiro verificar antes de cada linha de código identada se o número de espaços/tabs está correto. Separar a classe de cima da de baixo por uma linha em branco também é bom (embora eu *acho* que não tem nada a ver com o erro).

Comment: O erro é provavelmente a edentação mesmo, muitos iniciantes em *python* cometem esse erro, e a linha 12 também estaria errada por `Nome` não estar definido.

Comment: Vou verificar mas obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: Quando tiver um erro, cole a mensagem de erro - o Python fala queal é o erro, se você ler a mensagem com atenção, além do número da linha.

Agora - para ver aqui está certo - pode ser realmente mistura de espaços com tabs - configure seu editor de textos para usar 4 espaços na identação, nunca "tab"  (que é um caractére diferente de espaço)

Comment: Outra coisa -acho que você tá se enrolando no seu entendimento de OO aí- qualquer coisa, tem contato inbox no meu perfil.

Answer (score 0):

O código tem alguns erros conceituais, veja o código abaixo:

```
class Pai(object):
    Nome='Carlos'
    Sobrenome='Maria'
    Residencia='Rio de Janeiro'

class Filha(Pai):
    Nome='Luciana'
    def __init__(self, humor):
        Pai.__init__(self) # Lembre-se de sempre iniciar a classe pai
        self.humor = humor

f = Filha('alegre')
print(f.Nome)
print(f.Sobrenome)
print(f.Residencia)
```

Outras considerações:
Na linha `print(Nome.Pai)` não é possível obter, pois não há nenhuma instância de `Nome`. Caso queira encontrar o nome do pai, não será possível pois o atributo Nome foi sobrescrito pela classe filha.

O atributo `f.olho` é invalido, pois não existe na classe